# Encrypting folders on an sd card

Tags: video, encryption, sd-card, webcam, micro-sd-card

I bought a webcam you can use to take photos and videos in the normal way with the help of a micro SD card.

Can the individual folders of this SD card (or even the entire SD card) be encrypted, or alternately be hidden it from third parties, but the camera can still store the video files in it without any problems and thus still have access to this folder/SD card?

Comment: 1) How is the microSD card formatted; FAT, FAT32, exFAT, NTFS, ext4, or some other file system? 2) Which OS do you use it with; Windows, MacOS X, or Liinux (and if Linux, which distro and release number?) 3) Make and model of camera? Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Yeah I'll add those infos later, but I just found out that my SD card is dead so I'll wait until I get a new one before updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

If (parts) of the SD card were encrypted, both the computer and the webcam need to be able to decrypt its contents to be able to read/write from/to the SD card.

IOW, if the webcam has the ability to encrypt the SD cards' contents, the computer would need the same ability and vice versa. I have not heard of encrypting webcams, but I'm sure they exist though. If so, the computer would then need some kind of decrypting program to read from it.

Does that answer help?